# C++ function in main doesn't work

Tags: c++

Why doesn't this code print the letter a?

```
#include <iostream>      
#include <stack>         
void a()
{
    std::cout<<"a";
}
int main ()
{
  void a();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the `void a();`, it's only `a();`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're accidentally declaring a function inside `main()` instead of calling it.

```
int main ()
{
  void a(); // <-- DECLARES a function, does not call it
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the fix:

```
int main ()
{
  a();
  return 0;
}
```

Also note that you probably want a newline:

```
void a()
{
    std::cout<<"a\n";
}
```

Or you can use `std::endl`, if you like typing.

Comment: Note that `std::endl` automatically flushes the output, which may decrease speed if called very often. (In contest programming, we are discouraged to use it because there the success of a solution can depend on single milliseconds).

Answer (score 4):

You're declaring your function twice:

```
#include <iostream>      
#include <stack>         
void a()
{
    std::cout<<"a";
}
int main ()
{
  void a(); // this is a declaration
  return 0;
}
```

Do this instead:

```
int main ()
{
  a(); // this is a function call, which will execute your function
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Its ok qwertyu uytrewq, everyone have these kind of problems in start, the main thing is never hesitate to question.

> The main error in your code is, that you are declaring the function but not calling it. There are three phases of functions.

1. Declaration i.e

   void a();
2. Definition i.e

   void a ()
   {
   std::cout << "a";
   }
3. Calling a Function i.e

   a();

Now the major error in your program belongs to the 3rd phase (Calling a Function) you are mentioning the function type also which is know as Deceleration, so the correct code is as following.

```
#include <iostream>      
#include <stack>         
void a()
{
    std::cout<<"a";
}
int main ()
{
 a();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main function:

```
int main()
{
      // Don't add Void
   a();
    return 0;
}
```